# CMake could not find OpenGL (missing: OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY)

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, opengl

I'm trying to install freeglut-3.0.0 downloaded as source code from [sourceforge](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/).

When I type `cmake .` then it shows error `Could not find OpenGL (missing: OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY)`

As there are many questions and answers for this problem on stackoverflow, askubuntu and github. I tried given suggestions from these questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170869/cmake-could-not-find-opengl-in-ubuntu), [here](https://forum.kicad.info/t/trying-a-master-compile/20927), [here](https://blog.csdn.net/durongze/article/details/80300910), [here](https://github.com/pmh47/dirt/issues/47), [here](https://gitlab.orfeo-toolbox.org/orfeotoolbox/otb/-/issues/1752), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63275036/cmake-claims-finding-opengl-but-cant-find-egl-and-openglgl) and many others....) and when I install any package by following suggestions then I always get `package_name is already the newest version` but problem remains same.

In many suggestions and answers it is mentioned that these libraries are already installed by Nvidia driver and it seems that these libraries are installed in my PC but Cmake can't find it.

My PC configuration is

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Nvidia Driver 440.100

May be my this question seems to be duplicate of many questions but I'm unable to find any solution for my problem.

Looking for some kind suggestions.

Comment: Is the `mesa-common-dev` package installed? is the `/usr/include/GL/glx.h` file present?

Comment: @steeldriver yes mesa-common-dev is installed and `glx.h` is also exist in same location as you said.

Comment: having same issue compiling `ppsspp` any hope it get fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually partly thank ChatGPT for this, as I was also stumped.

1. Verify that you've got the needed .so files, and find the path to them

```bash
find /usr -name 'libGL.so'
# in my case, on a raspberry pi I get
# /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

2. I believe you can either modify the `CMakeLists.txt` or change the commandline arguments for cmake. 
    
   If you edit the cmake, add these two lines somewhere near the top.
   NOTE: the var names here are slightly different than the error message (but it still fixes the problem, at least for me)

```
set(OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so)
set(OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so)
```

3. If the cmake command still doesn't work, you can try the following sanity check.
   If you're using `ssh`, first reconnecting using

```bash
ssh -X blah_address 
# so that displays are enabled
```

Then (whether you're on ssh or not) do

```
DISPLAY=:0
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

The output should look something like:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Broadcom
OpenGL renderer string: VC4 V3D 2.1
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 22.2.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 22.2.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
```

If it doesn't, that means theres probably a problem with OpenGL itself, and is a seperate issue to go track down.